# On a incline is it ever possible for a object to be at a equilibrium?

Tags: forces, free-body-diagram

If a object is on a incline is it possible for all the forces to balance out? On a incline gravity causes the object to move, normal force would be keeping it up but would not be enough to overcome gravity. I know that friction causes a object to stop moving but would it ever possibly be large enough for the object to be at a equilibrium?

Comment: Why not do an experiment to find out? Prop up a tray or table at an angle, and see if you can balance an object on it without it falling off,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens very frequently.

If the object isn't moving, then there can't be any net acceleration on the object.  That means the forces are in equilibrium.

$$\sum F = ma$$therefore if $a = 0$, then $$\sum F = 0$$ meaning the forces are in equilibrium (sum of all forces is balanced).

Comment: Also the net torque is zero as the body might be capable of tipping over?